# Append a string value to where in (select distinct field from table)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to append a string value onto an `in` clause. E.g. this query retruns a field of string values:

```
with

lut as (
select *
from mytable
)

select distinct "primary goal" from lut
```

I can also do this:

```
select distinct "primary goal" from lut union all (select 'trial')
```

This returns the original data from the first select plus an additional row with value 'trial'.

I want to use this within a `where in` clause

```
with

lut as (
select *
from mytable
)

select *
from anothertable
where event_name in (select distinct "primary goal" from lut union all (select 'trial'))
```

Returns error:

> ERROR: Query unsupported due to an internal error. Detail: Unsupported query. Where: Oid: 1101.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result. You description is unclear and code is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the constant trail directly to the column, wound change nothing for the distinct, so ou would get the wanted result

```
with

lut as (
select *
from mytable
)

select distinct CONCAT('trial',"primary goal") from lut
```

IN Clause seems not fully be implemented

use `JOIN`

```
with

lut as (
select *
from mytable
)

select *
from anothertable a JOIN (select distinct "primary goal" as lut_name from lut union all (select 'trial')) t1
ON a.event_name = t1.lut_name
```

Comment: can you show me the **complete** error message